# Changing the height of the row causes issues

Tags: ios, uitableview

I got a problem with the Tableview-Cells in iOS.

I got a tableview with custon cells in it. I wanted to lower the height of the cells.
The row height in the tableview was set to 105, I changed it to 55 (the actual height of the custom cells wich are provided as xib-files).

So far, so easy, but now to my problem:
After the tableview loaded, it showed only one entry, but all the other entries aren't shown. If I scroll down and up again on the other hand, the previously hidden entries are shown.

I tried to work a little with the heigh-values in the tableview-options, and as I increase the heigh the more of a cell is shown on the first loading, but its never a complete cell until I set it to 105 again. Scrolling fixes the broken entries.
There is by far enough size on the screen and the cells height is exactly 55.

Has anyone here has an idea what could cause that problem?

As allways, thanks for any help.

Comment: are you using - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath on your class that is UITableViewDelegate ?

Comment: no, I don't use this function

Comment: So are you setting .rowHeight for table view ? Or you dynamically take height from xib ? If so - show us the code

Comment: No, I just changed it within the inspector. I got no code interfeering within this.

Comment: What content is in the cells? Are you using any views that are still set with a frame height of 105 as opposed to 55?